# Deploy parse-server-example to Heroku and automatically set serverURL

Tags: ios, heroku, environment-variables, parse-server

Need help with ideas on how to accomplish the following...

1. I forked `parse-server-example` and setup a deploy to heroku button on a web page.
2. When you hit deploy it sets some env variables I created, including one called `SERVER_URL`, but the best I can do is set it to: http://yourappname.herokuapp.com/parse  Literally that, because I don't know what yourappname is at this time.
3. Then you hit deploy for free and the name is generated.

I would then like to **automatically** set this config variable.  For my purposes I can't go set this variable through the Heroku dashboard.

I use an app.json file to set those config variables when the app is first deployed, but again, the app.json file is used before the server url is actually generated, so it stays set to http://yourappname.herokuapp.com/parse

If there was some kind of callback after hitting the deploy to Heroku button where I could set it from my backend with the Heroku API.  But I don't know if such a thing exists.

Why do I need this set?  Because I am using the mailgun adapter with the `publicServerURL` set to `process.env.SERVER_URL`.  I can't go back and set this manually, I need it to stay set to a variable.

I seriously doubt there is anyway to set this at runtime from my iOS app when I call `PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground` but just thinking of all options, because I do know my serverURL at runtime.

Looking for ideas... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to set this parameter dynamically:  Since I have the server url at runtime for my iOS app, I ended up setting the `SERVER_URL` config var on Heroku using the Platform API when my app launches.  Then by the time someone hits the forgot password button, parse-server can use `process.env.SERVER_URL`, which is now properly set.

To see how:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#config-vars